# gq in vim resulting in shell error

Tags: vim, zsh

When I highlight a line and press `gq` in visual mode I normally expect (neo)vim to wrap that line at a specific length; however, today neovim started overwriting the line with the following text:

```
zsh:1: unknown file attribute: v
```

This hasn't happened before today. Does `gq` normally call out to the shell? How can I determine what `gq` is calling and why `zsh` doesn't like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue for a while now, and I may have fixed it (fingers crossed). Formatting via `gq` is controlled by the `formatexp` or `formatprg` options, likely set by a plugin you are using. I grepped through my plugins for `formatprg` and `formatexp`, disabled and re-enabled each plugin until the culprit was found.

I could have simplified the process, because the issue only appeared in Typescript files, and the source ended up being `plugged/vim-polyglot/ftplugin/typescript.vim`. Since disabling / re-enabling it, the issue hasn't re-appeared (actually it has, see edit).

Hope this helps, cheers.

/edit For good measure and to verify this behavior, I updated my plugins again, and the issue re-appeared. I was able to verify that above plugin seems to be the issue (typescript.vim from the polyglot plugin). Creating an issue in the polyglot repository seems to be the next step here.

/edit Related issue: https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim/issues/209

/edit As a temporary workaround, you can disable the plugin. If you have it as part of polyglot, you can do: `let g:polyglot_disabled = ['typescript']`, and wait for the issue to be resolved.